# vb.net change ForeColor in specific DataGridView cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to change ForeColor in a specific DataGridView cell after edit.
I try to do this by:

```
Private Sub dgv_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv_.CellEndEdit
    dgv_.Item(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
End Sub
```

but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the indexes the wrong way around.  When you index the `Item` property, it's column first, then row:

```
dgv_.Item(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
```

You may have confused yourself because you do go row before column when you do it this way:

```
dgv_.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
```